# Как из фрагмента прослушивать метод активности?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-service

В фрагменте запускается на выполнение Служба:

```
mPendingIntent = getActivity().createPendingResult(TASK_CODE_1, new Intent(), 0);
Intent intent = TaskInService.newInstance(getContext());
intent.putExtra//some code
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

В Service я создаю отдельный поток (работаю с сетью и сохраняю данные в синглетный класс).

Далее, из сервиса уведомляю активность о проделанной работе:

```
pi.send(LeagueStandingFragment.STATUS_FINISH);
и срабатывает вызов в хостовой активности:

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //some code
}
```

Вопрос: как получать такие уведомления в фрагмент, чтобы производить обновление  его интерфейса?

Comment: Как вариант зарегистрировать BroadcastReceiver во фрагменте и через sendBroadCast из службы передавать данные